# Need help with op-amp comparator circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, single-supply-op-amp

I have two op-amps connected in series:

[image]

The first op-amp only acts as a voltage follower. It is connected to the voltage divider resistors and outputs V/2.

The second op-amp is acting as an inverting amplifier to amplify the input signal. The non-inverting input is connected to the first op-amp's output (which is V/2) and the inverting input is connected to the input signal. The output of the second op-amp is shown below.

I have to measure the width of the signal which is shown in red with an MCU, so I have to turn the side of the signal into a pulse length. I dont need the rest of the signal. How can I handle this?

[image]

The circuit is supplied by batteries which start from 9 V.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You want to measure the width of the signal, grab your oscilloscope, put 2 time markers and measure the width of the signal. What's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: oh, i'm sorry for bad english. i editted the question. i have to measure the signal length with MCU. The pulse continues 14 microseconds. the frequency is 500 HZ. i want somehow turn the side of signal to pulse width. how can i do it?

Comment: Have you simulated your circuit?

Comment: no i dont use any simulation software. i took this output from scope. i tried to put somecomparator circuit but i could not get full length

Comment: What is connected to pins 1 and 2 of J1?

Comment: wire as an inductor

Comment: How can you measure a signal that's not there? The red pulse does not correspond to the output of the amplifier. I don't read Cyrillic so I can't see the specs of that amplifier, and I can see it's likely a programmable current type that you've jacked up the current with the 22K R4 but is it fast enough (given that it has significant gain as well as the high frequency input)?

Comment: my question is about what kind of circuit can i add to this schematic to convert the blue signal to red one. then my plan is read the length of the pulse with MCU. the period of signal is 2 milliseconds.

Comment: The length of the red pulse appears to be unrelated to the blue signal. What determines the trailing edge timing?

Comment: the coil which connected to j1 determines the pulse length. if you see the blue signal is going down slowly. While the coil connected to j1 reacts something the length of blue signal starts to increase. I need to convert the falling edge of blue signal to pulse like red signal as shown

Comment: Sounds like  you're trying to detect a small signal difference of maybe 20mV (roughly 5\$\tau\$) on top of a dubiously stable 4.5V or so bias, with time resolution of what? It would require a fast and high-gain comparator and some attention to that bias. Too little info to speculate.